# area of triangle with dot product in matlab

Tags: matlab

i was recently introduced in matlab and i face some difficulties,i have to calculate the dot product of three vectors a[4,7], b[6,8] and c [3,12] which form a triangle and then find the angle between them and also the area of the triangle.Could you please give me some ideas??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to belong more at http://math.stackexchange.com/ and they might help you formulating it.

Comment: When you say dot product, it will return a 1x1 matrix for any two of your input vectors. Are you sure you need dot product or cross product. WHen you say vectors, you are asking for cross product - see dot and cross product definitions. Matrix multiplication is different. You want `cross(cross(A,B),C)` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

@Divakar is right, your question is not really about programming. By the way, since you asked it here:

dot product (scalar product) in Matlab: [`dot(a,b)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html) or `sum(a.*b)`
vector product in Matlab: `a*b`

The former might be used to get the angles and the latter to the area, I will let you figure out the rest.

Comment: thanks for the answers, i know it is mostly linked to maths but i was asked to compute it in matlab, a totally unknown field for me and i am completely lost and confused.